# How to create column names with groovy while running JMeter script in distributed mode

Tags: groovy, jmeter

Setup: JMeter 4.0, Groovy 2.4.13, 3 remote engines and one master

I have the following Script for saving variables into a file during test:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("\\\\FOOT1\\TEST1\\apache-jmeter-4.0\\bin\\company.txt"),true)
fileWriter.append("Phone_number" + ";" + "Name"+ System.getProperty("line.separator"))
fileWriter.close()
```

How do I make it so, to save the column name within my file on my master machine only once (and not three times) while being executed on three machines concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

You can amend your code to something like:

```
if (org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getLocalHostName().equals("some_of_your_slaves_hostname")) {
    //do what you need
}
```

Alternatives are using [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) functions from the Parameters section of the JSR223 Test Element. Something like:

[image: JMeter JSR223 Save Variables]

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Also be aware of [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property, you will be able to store JMeter Variables directly into .jtl results file.

Comment: I like to avoid this approach - JMeter does not guarantee that my selected "__machineName" will be the first to create the column names. I'm looking for a solution where the script checks if the column names do exist and disregards attempts from the remaining two machines